# Replace all hyphens with no spaces before or after it with spaces

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, string

I have a table that has a column with probably a few thousand occurrences of a phrase with dashes instead of spaces. For example:

```
my-name-is-jack
```

I need to find these occurrences and swap the dash with a space.
However, there are other phrases with dashes that have spaces before and/or after them that should not be changed. For example:

```
stackoverflow - a cool site for developers
```

How would I do something like this?

*I'm assuming I would do it with Regex, however I've never seen Regex used in Mysql.
I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks!

Comment: MySQL version???

Comment: If you search for "regex mysql" I'm sure you'll find plenty of examples of how to do it.

Comment: @SalmanA mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.59, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual solution is to replace the "substring that should not be touched" with a substring that cannot occur in your data, make the actual replacement, then undo the temporary replacement:

```
SELECT test, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(test, ' - ', '^^^'), '-', ' '), '^^^', ' - ') AS result
FROM (
    SELECT 'my-name-is-jack - stackoverflow' AS test
) AS tests
-- returns "my name is jack - stackoverflow"
```

Comment: This is what I came up with, based on your answer. I still got an error. I'm not sure what "test" is supposed to be. Could you explain? Thanks!

Comment: It is just an example that you could copy-paste in your favorite sql client. In real world you would replace test with your column name and `FROM () AS tests` with your actual FROM clause.

Comment: Well at least I didn't get any errors now. To clarify - table name is "fulls" and field name is "title". Where did I go wrong?

SELECT title, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(title, ' - ', '^^^'), '-', ' '), '^^^', ' - ') AS result FROM ( SELECT * from fulls where title = '[a-z0-9](-)[a-z0-9]' ) AS title

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Your where clause is obviously wrong... looks like a regex pattern instead of string.  Try `SELECT title, REPLACE(...) FROM fulls WHERE title LIKE '%-%'` or `SELECT title, REPLACE(...) FROM fulls WHERE title REGEXP '[a-z0-9]-[a-z0-9]'`